# old flex sdk download

Tags: apache-flex, sdk

Since old flex sdk download links don't work, 
and question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456540/where-else-find-a-download-link-of-flex-sdk-4
is closed,
maybe somebody have some other (private) link ... 
?

Comment: I can't believe this was reposted so soon after the old question was closed w/ massive down votes and then deleted.

Comment: Best to check the official blog: http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2012/05/looking-for-old-flex-sdks.html

Answer (score 10):

I just came across this from @zwetan for downloading 4.5.1:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/flex_sdk_4.5.1.zip

For older versions, I believe you can just adjust the url, so if I wanted 4.6, I just used:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/flex_sdk_4.6.zip and it dl'ed.

I don't know if that'll work for anyone else, but it's working currently for me.  I will now have my own copies for a bit.

Answer (score 7):

Found just the thing: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Downloads/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the code from the SVN Repository.  Try [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/tags) or [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/branches).

I just don't know which Flex 4.0 branch/tag is the release one.

Comment: Great, finally normal repository. Thanks!